# Set boolean to true, but filewriter still overwrites the file, any advice?

Tags: java, filewriter

I have created a simple program that sorts integers in an input file using different algorithms. I also use filewriter to output results to another file. Unfortunately no matter how I change my code, file gets overridden. Any advice?

Been searching for answer on google and tried changing the way I input the syntax but nothing works.

important bits:

setting the writer up

```
try {

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter ("Sorted output.txt");

        //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter (fileWriter);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("Sorted output.txt", true));
```

outputting to the file

```
 out.println("User's own data set sorted using bubble sort.");
                      out.println(unsortedArray + Arrays.deepToString(FileOne));
                      out.println("Sorted Array looks like this:" + Arrays.toString(intArrayBubble));
                      out.println(timeToSort + bubbleSortIs + bubbleTime + "ms");
```

it works fine, however its used in a do while loop, with nested if statements, and each one overrides the other.

Rest of code in case its required - UPDATED - still not working

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PDD_Sorting {

    public static void main (String [] pArgs) 
    {

        //Array for a file
        String[] FileOne;
        FileOne = new String[0];



        int optionOne = 1,
            optionTwo = 2,
            optionThree = 3,
            secondaryOptionOne = 1,
            secondaryOptionTwo = 2,
            secondaryOptionThree = 3,
            userSelection,
            subUserSelection;

        String     unsortedArray = "Unsorted array is: ",
                   bubbleSort = "Sorted array using bubble sort: ",
                   selectionSort = "Sorted array using selection sort: ",
                   insertionSort = "Sorted array using insertion sort: ",
                   timeToSort = "Time needed to sort this array using ",
                   bubbleSortIs = "bubble sort is ",
                   selectionSortIs = "selection sort is ",
                   insertionSortIs = "insertion sort is ",
                   welcomeToSorter = "Welcome to the SORTER - program that can sort your txt files containing integeres in an ascending order!",
                   notFiles = "Integers, not files :)",
                   pleaseSelect = "Please select one of the following options, by enetering a number asociated with it.",
                   optionOneUserInput = "1. Sort your own data set - input your own set of data (integers, separated by colons, no spaces) into the Input file.",
                   optionTwoPredefined = "2. Use predetermind set of data to test the algorythms.",
                   optionThreeExit = "3. Exit the program.",
                   subMenuPleaseSelect = "Please select which algorythm would you like to use to sort this file.",
                   optionBubble = "(1) - Bubble Sort.",
                   optionSelection = "(2) - Selection Sort.",
                   optionInsertion = "(3) - Insertion Sort.",
                   usersDataBubble = "User's own data set sorted using bubble sort.",
                   sortedArrayLooks = "Sorted Array looks like this:",
                   msTime = "ms",
                   usersDataSelection = "User's own data set sorted using selection sort.",
                   usersDataInsertion = "User's own data set sorted using insertion sort.",
                   validOption = "Please enter a valid option i.e. 1,2 or 3",
                   lessThanZero = "If time shown in ms is 0, that means the time needed to conduct the sort is shorter than 1ms.",
                   fileCreated = "File created.",
                   terminatingProgram = "Terminating the program.",
                   unableToWriteFile = "Unable to write to file";


        System.out.println(welcomeToSorter);
        System.out.println(notFiles);

        Scanner tInput = new Scanner (System.in);

        try {

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter ("Sorted output.txt");

        //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter (fileWriter);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("Sorted output.txt", true));

        do {

            System.out.println(pleaseSelect);
            System.out.println(optionOneUserInput);
            System.out.println(optionTwoPredefined);
            System.out.println(optionThreeExit);

        //  Scanner tInput = new Scanner (System.in);
            userSelection = tInput.nextInt();

            if (userSelection == optionOne) {
                //System.out.println("Please enter a valid path for your file.");
                String[] splitFile = null;
                //String userFile = tInput.next();
                FileOne = getAndPrepareFile(splitFile);

                System.out.println(subMenuPleaseSelect);
                System.out.println(optionBubble);
                System.out.println(optionSelection);
                System.out.println(optionInsertion);
                subUserSelection = tInput.nextInt();

                if (subUserSelection == secondaryOptionOne) {
                    int size = FileOne.length;
                      int [] intArrayBubble = new int [size];
                      for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                         intArrayBubble[i] = Integer.parseInt(FileOne[i]);
                      }

                      bubbleSort(intArrayBubble);
                      long bubbleTime = timeCount(intArrayBubble);

                      out.println(usersDataBubble);
                      out.println(unsortedArray + Arrays.deepToString(FileOne));
                      out.println(sortedArrayLooks + Arrays.toString(intArrayBubble));
                      out.println(timeToSort + bubbleSortIs + bubbleTime + msTime);



                }

                else if (subUserSelection == secondaryOptionTwo) {
                    int size2 = FileOne.length;
                      int [] intArraySelection = new int [size2];
                      for(int i=0; i<size2; i++) {
                         intArraySelection[i] = Integer.parseInt(FileOne[i]);
                      }

                      doSelectionSort(intArraySelection);   
                      long selectionTime = timeCount(intArraySelection);

                      out.println(usersDataSelection);
                      out.println(unsortedArray + Arrays.deepToString(FileOne));
                      out.println(sortedArrayLooks + Arrays.toString(intArraySelection));
                      out.println(timeToSort + selectionSortIs + selectionTime + msTime);       

                }

                else if (subUserSelection == secondaryOptionThree) {
                     int size3 = FileOne.length;
                      int [] intArrayInsertion = new int [size3];
                      for(int i=0; i<size3; i++) {
                         intArrayInsertion[i] = Integer.parseInt(FileOne[i]);
                      }

                      doInsertionSort(intArrayInsertion);
                      long insertionTime = timeCount(intArrayInsertion);

                      out.println(usersDataInsertion);
                      out.println(unsortedArray + Arrays.deepToString(FileOne));
                      out.println(sortedArrayLooks + Arrays.toString(intArrayInsertion));   
                      out.println(timeToSort + insertionSortIs + insertionTime + msTime);

                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(validOption);
                    tInput.next();
                }

            }

            else if (userSelection == optionTwo){
                //file being prepared and loaded via function
                String[] splitFilePredefined = null;
                FileOne = getAndPrepareFilePredefined(splitFilePredefined);

                //converting string array into int array so the method can sort it.
                int size = FileOne.length;
                  int [] intArrayBubble = new int [size];
                  for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                     intArrayBubble[i] = Integer.parseInt(FileOne[i]);
                  }

                  int size2 = FileOne.length;
                  int [] intArraySelection = new int [size2];
                  for(int i=0; i<size2; i++) {
                     intArraySelection[i] = Integer.parseInt(FileOne[i]);
                  }

                  int size3 = FileOne.length;
                  int [] intArrayInsertion = new int [size3];
                  for(int i=0; i<size3; i++) {
                     intArrayInsertion[i] = Integer.parseInt(FileOne[i]);
                  }

                  //inserting pre-prepared int arrays into variables including a timecount method
                    int bubbleTime = timeCount(intArrayBubble);
                    int selectionTime = timeCount(intArraySelection);
                    int insertionTime = timeCount(intArrayInsertion);

                  //sorting array using various sorts
                    bubbleSort(intArrayBubble);
                    doSelectionSort(intArraySelection);     
                    doInsertionSort(intArrayInsertion); 

                    //out.println("Sorted arrray using insertion sort looks like this: " + Arrays.toString(intArrayInsertion));
                    out.println(timeToSort + bubbleSortIs + bubbleTime + "ms");
                    out.println(timeToSort + selectionSortIs + selectionTime + "ms");
                    out.println(timeToSort + insertionSortIs + insertionTime + "ms");
                    out.println(lessThanZero);

                    System.out.println(fileCreated); 

            }

            else if (userSelection == optionThree){
                System.out.println(terminatingProgram);
                System.exit(0);

            }
            else {
                System.out.println(validOption);
                tInput.next();
            }

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            //tInput.close();
        }while (userSelection != optionThree);  


        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println(unableToWriteFile);
            tInput.next();
        }


        tInput.close();

    }//end main     

    //method that fetches the file from predefined, hardcoded location and removes comas, esentially prepares the file for the next phase
    private static String[] getAndPrepareFile (String[] splitFile)

    {

        Scanner fileIn = null;

        try 
        {

            fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Greg\\Documents\\Programming\\PDD - Assignment 1\\Input.txt"));

            String fileNew = fileIn.next();

            splitFile = fileNew.split(",");

            //System.err.println(Arrays.toString(splitFile)); //Arrays.toString needed to print the array correctly, otherwise it prints the address of the object

            fileIn.close();


        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

            System.out.println("File not found.");
            //System.exit(0);
        }
        return splitFile;



    }   
    //as above but works for predefined file, that can be generated using randomNumber.java program
    private static String[] getAndPrepareFilePredefined (String[] splitFilePredefined)
    {

        Scanner fileIn = null;

        try 
        {

            fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Greg\\Documents\\Programming\\PDD - Assignment 1\\Generated input.txt"));

            String fileNew = fileIn.next();

            splitFilePredefined = fileNew.split(",");

            //System.err.println(Arrays.toString(splitFile)); //Arrays.toString needed to print the array correctly, otherwise it prints the address of the object

            fileIn.close();


        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

            System.out.println("File not found.");
            //System.exit(0);
        }
        return splitFilePredefined;



    }   
    //method used to sort a file using bubble sort
    private static void bubbleSort(int[] arr) { 


        int n = arr.length;  
        int temp = 0;  
         for(int i=0; i < n; i++){  
                 for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
                          if(arr[j-1] > arr[j]){  
                                 //swap elements  
                                 temp = arr[j-1];  
                                 arr[j-1] = arr[j];  
                                 arr[j] = temp;  
                         }  

                 }  
         }  

    }  
    //method used to sort a file using selection sort
    private static int[] doSelectionSort(int[] arr){

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
                if (arr[j] < arr[index]) 
                    index = j;

            int smallerNumber = arr[index];  
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;
        }
        return arr;
    }
    //method used to sort a file using sinsertion sort
    private static int[] doInsertionSort(int[] input){

        int temp;
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
            for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--){
                if(input[j] < input[j-1]){
                    temp = input[j];
                    input[j] = input[j-1];
                    input[j-1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
    //method used to calculate how much time has lapsed while using any of the given sort methods, outputs in ms, if less than 1 ms, outputs 0ms
    private static int timeCount (int[] anArray)
    {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Arrays.sort(anArray);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        long timeInMillis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(end - start, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        //System.out.println("Time spend in ms: " + timeInMillis);

        return (int) timeInMillis;

    }

}//end class
```

File gets constantly overridden, how do i stop this and make it add to file instead?

Comment: Actually don’t close file inside try block, do it in finally block otherwise it won’t be closed if exception is thrown. Compiler will skip your close method and proceed to catch block, eventually your code won’t work correctly.

Comment: it cannot be there as the original print in int he try block the finally doesnt see it so it throws an error unable to resolve to variable

Comment: Any reason you make 2 file writer's?

Comment: @Ferrybig There were there as I didnt know If the other one will work on its own, but doesnt matter which one i comment out, still doesnt work. At the moment it will add to file, only one, first imput from the program, and no more. as soon as i terminate the program and start it again it will add again one input and thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the first `FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("Sorted output.txt");`; this is actually creating/overwriting the file, after which your PrintWriter opens it again for appending.

So, just change

```
// ... omitting beginning
try {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter ("Sorted output.txt");
    //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter (fileWriter);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("Sorted output.txt", true));
    do { 
// ... omitting rest
```

to

```
// ... omitting beginning
try {
    //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter (fileWriter);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("Sorted output.txt", true));
    do { 
// ... omitting rest
```

Comment: this will only cause the file to be overwritten on each run, but i think @Gregory-Sky wants to "append" the output each time the user selects a sorting algorithm in the menu

Comment: i tried that and it only prints option 1 1 bubble sort, without anything else, it will let me add multiple write ins to the file but all will be same, option 1 1 despite me hitting other keys.

Comment: @Gregory Sky Are you sure it's not running the correct code? I see you are printing "user's own data set sorted using bubble sort" in both option 1 and option 3, despite using different sort methods.

Comment: @M.Brynczka its just a type already fixed it. I tried running option 1,2 then 1,3 or 2 and 1,1 or any other combination and its always the first option i chose that gets printed all others are ignored

Comment: @Gregory Sky Make sure to also move the `out.close()` line outside of the loop, as Andres Martinez pointed out.

Comment: @M.Brynczka I did and then nothing is written to the file at all.

Comment: @Gregory Sky That's strange. I copied and pasted the code, and it works fine with the suggestions that were made. To be clear: you're removing the `fileWriter`, and keeping `out.flush()` where it is but moving `out.close()` to outside of the loop, right?

Comment: @M.Brynczka yes it is. I tried again (with the updated code) simple moving the `out.close()` outside the do while block and i see after each running that the output is appended to the file.

Comment: @M.Brynczka sorted, managed to get this running, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Move out.close() outside the loop

```
            else {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid option i.e. 1,2 or 3");
                tInput.next();
            }

            out.flush();
           /* THIS  -> out.close(); <- THIS */
            //tInput.close();
        }while (userSelection != optionThree);  
         out.close();

        }
```

I tried your code and your problem is not that the file is being overwritten, but that you are closing the outputstream in the first iteration.

Comment: I did that and it makes no difference, but the file generated is empty with no output